# office365 microsoft graph full text search

Tags: rest, office365, microsoft-graph-api

Does the Microsoft Graph provide any full text search capability, in either v1.0 or beta?

Specifically I want to search over email body content. I have tried the following requests just to test out the different parts of the API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=body/content eq 'test'
```

with response message

```
The property 'Body' does not support filtering.
```

and request

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=startswith(subject,'test')
```

with response message

```
'contains' and 'startswith' are not supported for filtering.  Use Search instead.
```

This last response mentions some Search function, but I can't find this mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for the Search function is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search=test

Some more info here: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398167

Comment: Thanks, this works well! Were you able to find any official documentation from Microsoft on the search functionality? $search looks powerful but it would be great to get some details on it.